# page.click use value attribute as selector?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Problem:

The selector might randomly change due to various reasons, therefore, using the selector doesn't guarantee success all the time. Here is my code with the selector.

```
await page.click('body > div.api-container > div > div.clearAll > form > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(3)');
```

Is it possible to instead use page.click to click an element based on the **"value"** attribute? Here is the HTML:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Accept">
```

As you can see the value will always equal "Accept" and it would be easier to search the page and click the matching element.

Based on my research it looks like `page.$x(expression)` would work but I'm unsure how to write the expression.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to instead use page.click to click an element based on the "value" attribute?

It is, and you already have a variety of that in your initial selector, I'm talking about `input[type=submit]`. Instead of `type` there can be any other property of an element, including `value`:

```
await page.click('input[value="Accept"]');
await page.click('input[name="submit"]');
```

You could even omit type of element and search by its property only: `'[value="Accept"]'`, but keep in mind that this approach can potentially find several results, and [only the first of them will be clicked](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) (quite possibly, not the one you had in mind), so do test selector in a real browser's console first.